# Convert moblie gasture to mouse input

Tags: unity-game-engine

i use Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x in moblie device, now i switch to windows?

how can i convert Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x to Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) then drag left and right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct conversion between the two. I would create method, what returns the value, and implement the logic per platform. Something like this:

```
#if UNITY_STANDALONE
private Vector2 _prevPos;
#endif

private void Update()
{
    if (IsPointer())
    {
        Vector2 delta = GetDeltaPos();
        // do the work
    }
}

private bool IsPointer()
{
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    return Input.touchCount > 0;
#elif UNITY_STANDALONE
    return Input.GetMouseButton(0);
#endif
}

private Vector2 GetDeltaPos()
{
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    return Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
#elif UNITY_STANDALONE
    Vector2 ret = Input.mousePosition - _prevPos;
    _prevPos = Input.mousePosition;
    return ret;
#endif
}
```

I know it's not nice, but works on both platforms.